# asp-for binding and route-value issues inside loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am building a little website where users can manage personal gear, which has a name and mass among other properties.  I want to display all of this gear in a table, using input boxes bound to each item so the user can change values if desired, then hit an edit button and update the gear database.  I can get my foreach loop to bind all of the right values, but when it routes to the handler, it always sets the EditGearName and EditGearMass value to whatever value is in the first row.

```html
<table>
  @foreach (var g in Model.Gears) {
  <tr class="list-table-main">
    <td><input class="form-control" asp-for="EditGearName" value="@g.GearName" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" asp-for="EditGearMass" value="@g.Mass" type="number" min="0" /></td>
    <td style="width:12.5%"><button type="submit" asp-page-handler="EditGear" asp-route-groupid="@gg.ID">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Here is an example of my handler method called on the button press. The GearBL.EditGear method is code behind that handles saving it to database.  I know this works (so long as the right values are passed in)

```
public IActionResult OnPostEditGroup(int groupid)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnGetParent();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EditGearName))
                    throw new ValidationException("Gear name must not be empty");
                if (EditGearMass < 0)
                    throw new ValidationException("Gear mass cannot be less than 0");

                GearBL.EditGear(groupid, User, EditGearName, EditGearMass, false);

                Response.Redirect("GearList");
            }
            catch (Core.Domain.ValidationException ve)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ve.Message);
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

I am new to asp.net/razor so any help would be appreciated.  I'm not sure I even have the best way to implement something like either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it always sets the EditGearName and EditGearMass value to whatever value is in the first row.

You should add the form tag in the foreach loop to enable one submit for one row.

```
<table>
    <form>
    @foreach (var g in Model.Gears) {
    <tr class="list-table-main">
        <td><input class="form-control" asp-for="EditGearName" value="@g.GearName" /></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" asp-for="EditGearMass" value="@g.Mass" type="number" min="0" /></td>
        <td style="width:12.5%"><button type="submit" asp-page-handler="EditGear" asp-route-groupid="@gg.ID">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    }
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: I was unsure that it would pass the right value because it throws a warning "Element 'form' cannot be nested inside element 'table', but it still works!  Thanks.

Comment: Will do! I also decided to change from a table to a collection of div tags so that it is more proper HTML (since <form> tags shouldn't be inside tables).

Comment: @FlippinsweetBen, yeah, a div collection is more appropriate.